# Как сделать так, чтобы значение request.user кастомной User-модели сохранялось между страницами?

Tags: python, django

Суть проблемы заключается в том, что строка login(request, obj) вроде как и логинит пользователя, заполняя request.user, но только до того времени, пока не возвращается response. Потом request.user заполняется анонимным пользователем, несмотря на то, что в куках запись sessionid создается.

/project/user/models.py

```
import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, UserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models

class MyUserManager(UserManager):
    def create(self, **kwargs):
        user = super().create(**kwargs)
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()
        return user
    def get(self, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('email', None) is not None:
            return super().get(email=kwargs['email'])
        return None

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    password = models.TextField()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'password']
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    objects = MyUserManager()
```

/project/admission/backend.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend
from user.models import User

class Backend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request=None, username=None, email=None, password=None):
        if None in [email, password]:
            return None
        scope = locals()    
        data = {i: eval(i, scope) for i in ['username', 'email', 'password'] if eval(i, scope) is not None}
        try:
            password = data.pop('password')
            user = User.objects.get(**data)
            if not user.check_password(password):
                return None
        except:
            return None
    return user
```

/project/admission/views.py

```
from .forms import RegistrationForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from user.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import login

def registration(request):
    data = {i: request.POST.get(i, None) for i in ['username', 'password', 'email']}
    form = RegistrationForm()
    response = render(request, 'admission/registration.html', context={'form': form})
    if None not in data.values():
        if len(User.objects.filter(email=data['email'])) == 0:
            obj = User.objects.create_user(username=data['username'], email=data['email'], password=data['password'])
            login(request, obj)
            response = redirect('/')
    return response
```

/project/project/settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.User'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['admission.backend.Backend']
```

Нужно ли будет переписывать функцию login(), или проблема кроется в другом?

Comment: А было ради чего все так усложнаять? Наследовал бы от auth.User и все бы работало

Comment: @eri , Ок, все то, что отличает мою модель от django.contrib.auth.models.User - это поля username и email. Как реализовать мою задумку путем наследования? Обычное переписывание этих атрибутов в сабклассе вызывает ошибку: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'email' in class 'User' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'User'.

Comment: зачем их переписывать если они уже есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что бэкенд аутентификации является классом, который реализует два обязательных метода: get_user и authenticate (первый из которых я не прописал). Лично в моем коде я подправил методы модели MyUserManager и, собственно, добавил необходимый метод в Backend:
/project/user/models.py

```
class MyUserManager(UserManager):
    def create(self, **kwargs):
        user = super().create(**kwargs)
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()
        return user
    def get(self, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('email', None) is not None:
            return super().get(email=kwargs['email'])
        elif kwargs.get('id', None) is not None:
            return super().get(id=kwargs['id'])
        return None
```

/project/admission/backend.py

```
class Backend:
    def authenticate(self, request=None, username=None, email=None, password=None):
        if None in [email, password]:
            return None
        scope = locals()    
        data = {i: eval(i, scope) for i in ['username', 'email', 'password'] if eval(i, scope) is not None}
        try:
            password = data.pop('password')
            user = User.objects.get(**data)
            if not user.check_password(password):
                return None
        except:
            return None
        return user
    def get_user(self, iden):
        return User.objects.get(id=iden)
```